# How can I remove "holes" in indexes of an array?

Tags: arrays, bash

Excuse me, but I don't know the proper way for spelling this. I hope the example will explain my problem:

```
$ array[1]=john
$ array[2]=smith
$ array[4]=jane
$ array[5]=doe
$ echo ${array[@]}
john smith jane doe
$ echo ${array[3]}

$
```

I would like some method to **remove** the "hole" at position 3 in `array`, so that:

- Value `jane` would be moved to position 3.
- Value `doe` would be moved to position 4.
- Value at position 5 would become empty (unset).
- Array length (4 in this example) would not become changed.

Is it needed to program any **loops(s)** through the array to obtain this, or there is some **simpler** method?

Further data:

- Assuming **Bash** as shell.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the elements to create a new array:

```
$ array=([1]=john smith [4]=jane doe)
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([1]="john" [2]="smith" [4]="jane" [5]="doe")'
$ array=("${array[@]}")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="john" [1]="smith" [2]="jane" [3]="doe")'
```

Note that this counts from 0, not 1. If you really need a 1-based array, add a dummy element to the new array then delete it.

```
$ array=(foo "${array[@]}")
$ unset 'array[0]'
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([1]="john" [2]="smith" [3]="jane" [4]="doe")'
```

Comment: A clean and good solution, Chepner. Why single quotes for the `unset` command instead of double quotes?

Comment: No real reason; single quotes look less "noisy" to me, but both types of quotes would work the same here.